# Value greater than 1 for probability

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

> There is a committee of 11 people where 3 people are from Group A, 6
> from Group B, and 2 from Group C. The first part is to find the number
> of ways they can sit, if people in the same group are
> indistinguishable. Now the second part is to find the probability that
> the first and last people in the row are from different groups.

So far, I have found out 6 cases for this part but when I am adding them and dividing by the value obtained in part 1, my probability is coming out to be greater than 1. Can someone help me figure out where I am going wrong? My value for the first part is:

$$\frac{{11!}}{{3! \times 6! \times 2!}} $$

My Values for the second part are:

1. First person - Group A and last person - Group B:
   $$ C(3, 1) \cdot C(6, 1) \cdot \frac{{9!}}{{2! \cdot 5! \cdot 2!}}$$
2. First person - Group A and last person - Group C:
   $$ C(3, 1) \cdot C(2, 1) \cdot \frac{{9!}}{{2! \cdot 6! \cdot 1!}}$$
3. First person - Group B and last person - Group A:
   $$ C(6, 1) \cdot C(3, 1) \cdot \frac{{9!}}{{2! \cdot 5! \cdot 2!}}$$
4. First person - Group B and last person - Group C:
   $$ C(6, 1) \cdot C(2, 1) \cdot \frac{{9!}}{{3! \cdot 4! \cdot 2!}}$$
5. First person - Group C and last person - Group A:
   $$ C(2, 1) \cdot C(3, 1) \cdot \frac{{9!}}{{2! \cdot 6! \cdot 1!}}$$
6. First person - Group C and last person - Group B:
   $$ C(2, 1) \cdot C(6, 1) \cdot \frac{{9!}}{{3! \cdot 4! \cdot 2!}}$$

Comment: I have added what values I got for the second part

Comment: You shouldn't have any of those $C(m,1)$ factors in the counts.

Comment: Since people from a group are indistinguishable, you are overcounting all arrangements by first *choosing* those to be at the ends !

Comment: If you're trying to debug, please tell us the *difference*.

Comment: @trueblueanil, so I should remove, C(p,1). C(q,1) and then calculate for each case?

Comment: @PsychBit: Yes, from the $6$ expressions, just removing the first two terms will give the answer for each case, then add them up.

Comment: @trueblueanil, thanks a lot, I am getting the correct answer now

Comment: @PsychBit:You're welcome !

Comment: One warning for the future: _Unordered_ selection often doesn't mix well with probability.  It doesn't matter in this case, because each unordered way of choosing is given by the same number ($3! \times 6! \times 2!$) of ordered elements.  It is simple to see that the ordered elements are equally likely, so the unordered case also gives equally likely cases.  (this is also why both solutions given at the moment work)

Answer (score 3):

For the second part, as has been pointed out, you are overcounting by having the $m \choose 1$ factors.

Here's one way to solve the second part.

We start by counting the number of ways in which the first and the last persons in the row are from the same group. We have three cases.

1. They are from Group A. The number of ways would be $\dfrac{9!}{6! \times 2!}$.
2. Group B. The number of ways =  $\dfrac{9!}{3! \times \times 4! \times 2!}$.
3. Group C. The number of ways = $\dfrac{9!}{3! \times  6!}$.

Add these and subtract from $\dfrac{11!}{3! \times 6! \times 2!}$ to get the number of ways in which the first and the last persons are from different groups.

Comment: Oh okay, I get your method. Doing the question again using your method gives me 3024. As pointed out by others, I had overcounted and so now I am getting the same answer using my method and yours.

Comment: I am glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

Your first part *ignores the order* but your second part does since the first and last person are no longer indistinguishable, hence the mismatch.

Just simply take the order into account in the second part. It would make it easier

The number of ways of arranging $11$ people is $11!$

1. If the first person and the last person are from group A: $9!\cdot3\cdot2$
2. If the first person and the last person are from group B: $9!\cdot6\cdot5$
3. If the first person and the last person are from group B: $9!\cdot2\cdot1$

Hence the probability that the first and last are from two different groups is

$P = 1-\dfrac{9!}{11!}(3\cdot2 + 6\cdot5 + 2\cdot 1)$